# Rotate 2D plane curve to create 3D object - solid of revolution - Rhino3D

Tags: 3d

Often, when making simple 3D models, one can intuitively create their 2D version and then just somehow turn this version in 3D model.

In my case, I'm trying to make ant egg model and this is my 2D curve:

[image: curve in rhinoceros]

The rings are illustrating the [rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution) I want to achieve to get the 3D model - almost cylindric egg.

How can I do this in Rhinoceros 3D?

Comment: Contrary to many other software, the "Help" files in Rhino are great. I highly recommend for you to take a look at them.

Comment: I've been searching and fiddling for 20 minutes (I'm quite sure about that) before posting. I found answer using wikipedia, few minutes before I got answer here. My problem is, that I'm running Czech Rhinoceros and even though my version is multi-language, [I can't find out how to switch to english](http://superuser.com/q/837920/194976). This makes every search complicated, as most files are in english.

Comment: Off the top of my head it should be in: "Rhino options > Options > Appearance". If you can't find it, you could try this: http://wiki.mcneel.com/rhino/addlanguages  and remove any other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the horizontal piece (the one on the XY plane) is the plan of the egg shape then lose the verticals (the rings on the XZ plane), they're just confusing you. Draw a single line the long way across the flat shape. Now `revolve` the flat profile around that line as the axis.

If that's not the plan, then make it the plan.

Comment: Rings were there to illustrate axis around which I want to rotate. the `_Revolve` command was what I was looking for.